Constantly getting redirected to login and home pages
As of recently I am constantly being redirected to the login and home pages on various sites.
The redirects happen as follows: I am browsing the site, clicking on a couple things, and here and there it redirects to the login or home page. Sometimes only once on the same site, other times multiple successive redirects.
I use chrome on a lenovo yoga slim 7 pro.
No idea what else to do except for resetting the pc or running over it with a rented tank.
I have deleted cache, gone incognito, played around with cookies, allowing, not allowing popups, updating and changing the browser, multiple virus scans with McAfee.

This question should likely be moved to superuser.com
